# Account restricted because Identity confirmation failed

Tags: facebook, facebook-business-manager

We have been using this Facebook account along with our Facebook business account. We currently have about 440+ client apps under our business account. Now our facebook account is restricted  because Identity confirmation failed and we missed the deadline to submit the details and 100+ of our apps got restricted.

I tried to find a way to contact facebook help regarding this matter. But I can't find a way to contact them.
Is there any way we can contact Facebook support and move this Business account along with all of our apps to an authentic Facebook account of one our business administrators to avoid future issues?

Comment: There is very little in terms of _direct_ contact - understandably, because with a platform this size, they would be likely to be absolutely inundated with support requests, if they gave out any direct contact options. Are you not given any ways to appeal this restriction from within the business manager UI?

Comment: @CBroe I don't see any option to appeal in the business manager. In the Developer Appeals page there's a option to appeal. when I sent the appeal through it I got the response saying 

"Apologies, but this channel is for developers that are restricted from creating apps.

For issues with your user account, Facebook.com, using an app you didn’t create, or for feature requests and bug reports for items other than the Platform APIs, please visit the Help Center:
https://www.facebook.com/help/ "

Comment: So "this Facebook account" means, a user account? Did you create a "fake" one for this purpose? (Facebook doesn't like that. Everyone developing apps should use their own, personal account to do so.) You can try and file a "bug report" under https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/, someone should look at those sooner or later at least. (But if might simply result in them closing the bug report as not on topic.)

Comment: @CBroe Yeah that's correct. Now we want to move it to an authentic account. For this we can't find a way to contact someone from facebook support. Not even from the business manager support pages.